# Update dataframe column efficiently using some hashmap method in R

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, data-mining

I am new to R and can't figure out what I might be doing wrong in the code below and how I could speed it up.
I have a dataset and would like to add a column containing average value calculated from two column of data. Please take a look at the code below (WARNING: it could take some time to read my question but the code runs fine in R):

first let me define a dataset **df** (again I apologize for the long description of the code)

```
> df<-data.frame(prediction=sample(c(0,1),10,TRUE),subject=sample(c("car","dog","man","tree","book"),10,TRUE))
> df
   prediction subject
1           0     man
2           1     dog
3           0     man
4           1    tree
5           1     car
6           1    tree
7           1     dog
8           0    tree
9           1    tree
10          1    tree
```

Next I add a the new column called **subjectRate** to df

```
df$subjectRate <- with(df,ave(prediction,subject))
> df
       prediction subject subjectRate
    1           0     man         0.0
    2           1     dog         1.0
    3           0     man         0.0
    4           1    tree         0.8
    5           1     car         1.0
    6           1    tree         0.8
    7           1     dog         1.0
    8           0    tree         0.8
    9           1    tree         0.8
    10          1    tree         0.8
```

from the new table definition I generate a rateMap so as to automatically fill in new data with the subjectRate column initialized with the previously obtained average.

```
rateMap <- df[!duplicated(df[, c("subjectRate")]), c("subject","subjectRate")]
> rateMap
  subject subjectRate
1     man         0.0
2     dog         1.0
4    tree         0.8
```

Now I am defining a new dataset with a combination of the old subject in df and new subjects

```
> dfNew<-data.frame(prediction=sample(c(0,1),15,TRUE),subject=sample(c("car","dog","man","cat","book","computer"),15,TRUE))
> dfNew
   prediction  subject
1           1      man
2           0      cat
3           1 computer
4           0      dog
5           0     book
6           1      cat
7           1      car
8           0     book
9           0 computer
10          1      dog
11          0      cat
12          0     book
13          1      dog
14          1      man
15          1      dog
```

**My question:** How do I create the third column efficiently? currently I am running the test below where I look up the subject rate in the map and input the value if found, or 0.5 if not.

```
> all_facts<-levels(factor(rateMap$subject))
> dfNew$subjectRate <-  sapply(dfNew$subject,function(t) ifelse(t %in% all_facts,rateMap[as.character(rateMap$subject) == as.character(t),][1,"subjectRate"],0.5))
> dfNew
   prediction  subject subjectRate
1           1      man         0.0
2           0      cat         0.5
3           1 computer         0.5
4           0      dog         1.0
5           0     book         0.5
6           1      cat         0.5
7           1      car         0.5
8           0     book         0.5
9           0 computer         0.5
10          1      dog         1.0
11          0      cat         0.5
12          0     book         0.5
13          1      dog         1.0
14          1      man         0.0
15          1      dog         1.0
```

but with a real dataset (more than 200,000 rows) with multiple columns similar to *subject* to compute the average, the code takes a very long time to run. Can somebody suggest maybe a better way to do what I am trying to achieve? maybe some merge or something, but I am out of ideas.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect (but am not sure, since I haven't tested it) that this will be faster:

```
dfNew$subjectRate <- rateMap$subjectRate[match(dfNew$subject,rateMap$subject)]
```

since it mostly uses just indexing and `match`. It certainly a bit simpler, I think. This will fill in the "new" values with `NA`s, rather than 0.5, which can then be filled in however you like with,

```
dfNew$subjectRate[is.na(dfNew$subjectRate)] <- newValue
```

If the `ave` piece is particularly slow, the standard recommendation these days is to use the **data.table** package:

```
require(data.table)
dft <- as.data.table(df)
setkeyv(dft, "subject")
dft[, subjectRate := mean(prediction), by = subject]
```

and this will probably attract a few comments suggesting ways to eke a bit more speed out of that data table aggregation in the last line. Indeed, merging or joining using pure `data.tables` may be even slicker (and fast), so you might want to investigate that option as well. (See the very bottom of `?data.table` for a bunch of examples.)

Comment: Thank you so much. So far I only used the first two code snippets you posted and now it literally takes less than a second to process everything. I will definitely take a look at data.table also.

Comment: Hi. I missed this one at the time. The last line will be much faster and more elegant when `:=` by group is implemented: `dft[,subjectRate:=mean(prediction),by=subject]`.